# Restoring Safari web passwords from external drive?

Tags: safari, backup

Shortly before my MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021)‎ died, I'd backed it up onto an external drive.  Post death, I wasn't able to get any files off of it, so I bought a new MBP.

Most of my important info is already in the cloud, and I can cherry pick any other files I need.  But one has eluded me: Safari knew the passwords my various web accounts, and I'd like to get them back from the external drive.

So the short question: is there a file I can copy over from the external drive to my MBP such that Safari will once again be able to give me the passwords to my web accounts?

Comment: If you were using iCloud Keychain on the old Mac, then all you should need to do is sign in to iCloud and make sure it's enabled.

Comment: "most of my important information is already in the cloud"... how are you backing THAT up, and have you tested being able to get THAT back?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does Safari store passwords?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312057/where-does-safari-store-passwords)